# Java Generic Jackson Type Reference

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to make an ElasticSearch json to Object via the following.

```
ElasticResult<Record> records = ElasticUtils.getElasticResult("MyBeautifulJson");

public static <T> ElasticResult<T> getElasticResult(String json) throws Exception{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ElasticResult<T>>(){});
}
```

Which does not work, But what does work is

```
ElasticResult<Record> records = ElasticUtils.getElasticResult("MyBeautifulJson");
public static ElasticResult<Record> getElasticResult(String json) throws Exception{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ElasticResult<Record>>(){});
}
```

These two statements should be Identical right? I am not sure what I am doing wrong! If someone can explain that would be great :). Let me know if I need to post more code.

EDIT - ElasticResult Code

```
public class ElasticResult<T> {
    private int took;
    private boolean timed_out;
    private Shard _shards;
    private Hits<T> hits;

    public int getTook() {
        return took;
    }

    public void setTook(int took) {
        this.took = took;
    }

    public boolean isTimed_out() {
        return timed_out;
    }

    public void setTimed_out(boolean timed_out) {
        this.timed_out = timed_out;
    }

    public Shard get_shards() {
        return _shards;
    }

    public void set_shards(Shard _shards) {
        this._shards = _shards;
    }

    public Hits<T> getHits() {
        return hits;
    }

    public void setHits(Hits<T> hits) {
        this.hits = hits;
    }
}


public class Hits<T> {
    private int total;
    private long max_score;
    private List<Hit<T>> hits;

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public long getMax_score() {
        return max_score;
    }

    public void setMax_score(long max_score) {
        this.max_score = max_score;
    }

    public List<Hit<T>> getHits() {
        return hits;
    }

    public void setHits(List<Hit<T>> hits) {
        this.hits = hits;
    }
}


public class Hit<T> {
    private String _index;
    private String _type;
    private String _id;
    private String _score;
    private T _source;

    public String get_index() {
        return _index;
    }

    public void set_index(String _index) {
        this._index = _index;
    }

    public String get_type() {
        return _type;
    }

    public void set_type(String _type) {
        this._type = _type;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String get_score() {
        return _score;
    }

    public void set_score(String _score) {
        this._score = _score;
    }

    public T get_source() {
        return _source;
    }

    public void set_source(T _source) {
        this._source = _source;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you mapped jsontypes .
Post the type hierarchy of ElasticResult

Comment: The two things are not at all equivalent, but the explanation is incredibly complicated. The explanation involves type erasure and reflection. The short explanation is that type references require concrete types, not type parameters - `new TypeReference<ElasticResult<T>>(){}` isn't going to work.

Comment: I added the ElasticResult classes

Comment: @PaulBoddington Is there another solution that I can use? I am not sure how to accomplish this.